# Why .htaccess not blocking Folder in apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I am trying to block a direct access of a particular folder in apache .

My folder structure :
/var/www/html -  page.html
              - Private folder 
                 - css
                 -jss

I am trying to protect the private folder with password .

I done following steps :

1 . create a .htacess file in private folder .

.htacess file :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

2 . create a .htpasswd file in /etc/apache2 with `htpasswd`

3. Now i change some rules in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

But when i access to 10.0.0.1/private , i can able to browse this directory with out password .

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/>
     Options ExecCGI
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
Options All
</Directory>


AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Any other problem ? i set write permission to both `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/private/.htaccess
```

and

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/apache2/.htaccess
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should never use `.htaccess` if you can edit .conf files.

For your issue, when `AllowOverride` directive is set to `None`, .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.
You can try adding this to your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/private">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Comment: So should i remove `.htacess` file and include this  rule in to `apache2.conf `? and also i already added `AllowOverride All` in `<Directory /var/www/>`

Comment: For this Auth issue, remove `.htaccess` from `private/` folder and include this in `.conf`. If that was the only .htaccess, you can change `AllowOverride All` to `AllowOverride None`. If there were other .htaccess files, move their directives to `.conf` and then change `AllowOverride All` to `AllowOverride None`.

Comment: `.htaccess` is only meant to be used in cases where you don't have access to `.conf` files (shared hosting for example)